# Left Deep join tree in Database Query optimizer and parallelism

Tags: database, join, query-optimization

I read this in literature that left-deep join tree are less favorable than right deep tree as far as parallelism is concerned.
The reason given is as follows

```
          X
         / \
        /   \
       X     r6
      / \
     /   \
    X    r5
  /  
 /     \
r0     r1
```

In this join tree,according to literature, hash join would be performed in following way,

```
1. HashTable on r0 and then probe using r1
2. HashTable on r0 X r1 then hash probe using r5
3. HashTable on r0 X r1 X r5 and hash probe using r6
```

But a simpler parallel way of doing this join is

```
1. HashTable on r1, r5, r6 independently
2. HashProbe r1 using r0, use result to hash probe r5 and then r6
   This can be nicely pipelined.
```

Why cant it be done in this way ?
Am I missing something obvious ?

Ref:
    http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=1BBIHNuObz9vsFxaCtpKUeDg-Xif2kqRVnb0Mr_3IUah-RyTceFCANTq8drXW&hl=en_US ( Goto Page 18)

I also read similar thing in book : [http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Database-Processing-Applications-Management/dp/1558604340](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604340)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got how it works, all the places where I have read this, have assumption that HashBuild operation will always happen on left relation.
This explains why right-deep join tree will have better parallel execution plan that left-deep join tree.